# Filter SharePoint 2010 list web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, ssom

I have a Custom list view web part on a SharePoint Page. The List has a custom date field "Exam Date".

I need to filter the list items  based on current month, week and day. I don't want to use the calendar view or date filter.

I am looking to build a Custom web part for the solution. 
i.e. A drop down with the month /view or day values.

Can I set the filter criteria of the List View programmatically. 
i.e.

```
<View Name="{A8487F05-FCE5-45B5-8CB0-A47181FB968B}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Marketing" Url="/SchoolExamGCSE/Lists/GCSEResults/Exam.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
                <Query>
                    <Where>
                        <And>
                            <Geq>
                                <FieldRef Name="ExamStartDate"/>
                                <Value Type="DateTime">{ExamStartDate}</Value>
                            </Geq>
                            <Leq>
                                <FieldRef Name="ExamEndDate"/>
                                <Value Type="DateTime">{ExamEndDate}</Value>
                            </Leq>
                        </And>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
```

I did try the Date Filter and connect it to the web part but it only works if the date filter value is set . I do not want to show the date filter . I did set the date filter value programmatically but it required me do postback i.e.

```
setTimeout(__doPostBack(\'ctl00$m$g_13ee3dc5_7ede_4e1d_985f_647b1cb1317f$DateFilterPicker$DateFilterPickerDate\',\'\')";, 0);
```

Or

Can I just set the yiew programmatically like

```
SPWeb webSite = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
myListQuery.List = webSite.Lists["Exam"];

SPQuery query = new SPQuery(myListQuery.List.Views[3]);
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"ExamStartDate\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Body\"/>";
query.Query = "<Query><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='ExamStartDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>CurrentExamStartDate</Value></Leq></Where></Query>";

myListQuery.Query = query;
```

without having to set and pass the parameter

Answer (score 0):

On view's page (datefilter.aspx) add the webpart with html-form with your dropdown filter. It has to generate query string such as:

```
/Lists/List/datefilter.aspx?StartDate=2018-05-10&EndDate=2018-05-30
```

Open this page in SharePoint Designer and add parameters to listview web part:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="StartDate" Location="QueryString(StartDate)" />
<ParameterBinding Name="EndDateDate" Location="QueryString(EndDate)" />
```

Then modify CAML query for this view with your params:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="ExamDate"/>
      <Value Type="DateTime">{StartDate}</Value>
    </Geq>
    <Leq>
      <FieldRef Name="ExamDate"/>
      <Value Type="DateTime">{EndDate}</Value>
    </Leq>
  </And>
</Where>
```